# How do I make my java program run in the background?

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe

I want the program to be coded to run in the background, and have an icon in the tray. How do I do this? The OS is Windows, and the program is a JFrame.

Comment: Mac, Windows or Linux?  Does it require a UI at all?

Comment: you shd put more effort on learning how to ask a question.

Comment: This is a very incomplete question. Please read [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) to help you to improve your question lest it be closed.

Comment: I believe you're looking for a combination of `JFrame.setVisible(boolean);` and `SystemTray` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look ma, no windows here, just us teddies...

[image]

```
public class TestTrayIcon01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTrayIcon01();
    }

    public TestTrayIcon01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/SmallTeddy.png")));
                    SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
                    tray.add(icon);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setSize(100, 100);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

`JDialog` and `JWindow` (under Windows) will not display a "icon" on the task bar.  I'm pretty sure under Mac it's next to near impossible NOT to have a dock icon...

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there any way I can make it run in background when it is closed?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException. :( (And when the JFrame is closed)

Comment: Exception is gone. But the icon isn't the icon I want it to be. (I made the icon image the JFrame getIconImage)

Comment: 1. Make sure you've replaced the icon with one of your own, it needs to be embedded with the application (inside the Jar). 2. Don't set the `JFrame` to auto close